# In jQuery, how do I execute a function sequentially rather than simultaneously?

Tags: jquery

I'd like to be able to show and hide an element using jQuery's slideToggle function. When the element begins to start sliding out onto the screen, the 'border' class is toggled, so the element has a border as it slides in. However, when the element begins to slide out (when you click the button again), the border disappears as the slideToggle begins, not ends. So basically, I want the border to stay with the element as it slides out, and THEN disappear.

Here is the code cropped to my issue:

```
$('.button').on('click', function() {
    $('.sub').slideToggle();
    $('.sub').next().slideToggle();
    $('.divclass').toggleClass('border');
});
```

Comment: Most (if not all) the jquery animation functions allow for an additional parameter for 'complete' callback.  http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/  This will be called when the animation completes.

Answer (score 1):

Use a callback function like so

```
$('.sub').slideToggle( "slow", function() {
    $('.divclass').toggleClass('border');
  });
```

A callback will execute any code you put after the animation completes.

Comment: minor edit to state when the animation completes (not the method) as the method will 'complete' immediately.

Comment: @freedomn-m My bad for putting bad wording without realizing, thanks for that.